# unexpected t_variable php

Tags: php, syntax-error, openshift

I have written a simple php file on openshift.
I started with very simple operation (SQL) and I got following error:

```
[Sun Apr 06 11:59:35 2014] [error] [client 127.2.31.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/lib/openshift/53413f4a500446a9c8000172/app-root/runtime/repo/test.php on line 15
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo 'start';
    try{
        $dbh=new PDO("mysql:host=$_ENV{'OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'};dbname=$_ENV{'OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME'}",$_ENV{'OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'},$_ENV{'OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'}) or die('cannot connect db');//open a mysql database connection
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sth=$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM FS WHERE filename<>? AND desc<>?');
        $sth->execute(array('',''));
        $result=$sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print_r($result);
    }catch(PROException $err){
        echo $err->getMessage();
    }
    echo 'end';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I used [php checker](http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/) and it reported same error in line15.
I can't figure out the problem.
Thanks for help.

Comment: PROException - is it your defined custom Exception?

Comment: More likely a typo on PDOException...

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error lies here:

```
}catch(PROException $err){
```

Unless PROException was defined by you previously, as suggested by vp_arth, you probably meant PDOException.

```
}catch(PDOException $err){
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses square brackets to access array values, not curly brackets.

Change all your `$_ENV{'....'}` to `$_ENV['....']`

Answer (score 0):

$_[''] will not work inside of double quotes, i think you need it like this:

```
"{getenv('OPENSHIFT_ENV_VARIABLE')}"
```